# Javascript Dynamic array affecting the $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have created the following array indexes dynamically

```
var array=[];
array[4]=[];
array[6]=[];
array[100]=[];
```

then i have tried to add some data on that indexes

```
array[4].push({"id":3,"name":"dhaval"});
array[6].push({"id":6,"name":"harsh"});
array[100].push({"id":9,"name":"kevin"});
```

then when i am using the $.each for retrieving the data the $.each loop throught 0 to 100 .

```
$.each(array,function(key,item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

the problem is i have to check every time that is item is not undefined then and then the data might exists. so what is the possible solutions for loop only three times not the 100 times.

output :

> 4 undefined  javascript_Each.html:23
>
> [Object]     javascript_Each.html:23
>
> undefined    javascript_Each.html:23
>
> [Object]     javascript_Each.html:23
>
> 93 undefined javascript_Each.html:23
>
> [Object]

Comment: loop will execute 100 time, However you can check `item` is defined or not

Comment: Add: if(item!==undefined) to your loop...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the native `forEach` function instead of the jQuery `each` function. The `forEach` callback is not invoked for uninitialized values. That looks like this:

```js
var array = [];
array[4] = [];
array[6] = [];
array[100] = [];
array.forEach(function(item, key) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

In this case, the callback is invoked only three times.

Comment: thanx for this one bro @jobB

Answer (score 1):

It's happen because the $.each execute just the function if the value (item) be different of undefined.

If you run this code will show all positions:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];

a.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
});

// a
// b
// c
```

And [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to define dynamically variables